# Aplicar formato de línea en una leyenda de una gráfica multifactorial generada con tuberías

Tags: r

Con el siguiente código genero unos datos y luego imprimo "R" con una línea contínua y "W" con una línea discontínua.

Por motivos de organización y estética me gustaría separar los títulos de la leyenda en dos grupos: *Condición* para "H C" e "I C" y *Modelo* para "R" y "W". En la leyenda, en el caso de *Condición* representaríamos los colores, y en el de *Modelo* el tipo de de línea (discontínuo o no discontínuo) utilizando un negro estándar.

Al utilizar tuberías, el problema no es tan trivial, parece.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
tribble(    ~y,    ~cb,   ~z,    ~x,
            1     , 0,   "H C R"    ,1,
            2     , 1,   "H C R"    ,1,
            2     , 0,   "I C R"    ,1,
            3     , 1,   "I C R"    ,1,
            1.5   , 0,   "H C W"    ,1,
            2     , 1,   "H C W"    ,1,
            2     , 0,   "I C W"    ,1,
            2     , 1,   "I C W"    ,1,
            3     , 0,   "H C R"    ,2,
            3     , 1,   "H C R"    ,2,
            0.5   , 0,   "I C R"    ,2,
            2     , 1,   "I C R"    ,2,
            2     , 0,   "H C W"    ,2,
            2     , 1,   "H C W"    ,2,
            1     , 0,   "I C W"    ,2,
            1     , 1,   "I C W"    ,2)-> datos


aux<-datos %>%
  group_by(x, z, cb) %>%
  summarise(media = mean(y), 
            desvio = rnorm(1),#Tube que simular la desvio sd() arrojaba NaN                         
            error_est = desvio / sqrt(n()),             
            intervalo_sup = media + (2*error_est),       
            intervalo_inf = media - (2*error_est)) #%>%


library(RColorBrewer)
display.brewer.pal(11,name = "Spectral")  
brewer.pal(n = 11, name = "Spectral")
# Que la línea de condición "H C" apareciera en el color anaranjado que utiliza la paleta "Spectral".
# Que la línea de condición "I C" apareciera en el color verde oscuro que utiliza la paleta "Spectral".
colores<-brewer.pal(n = 11, name = "Spectral")[c(3,3,9,9)]




  ggplot() +

  geom_line(data=aux%>%filter(grepl("W",z)),
            aes(x = x, y = media, color = z,group = z),
            size=0.5,
            linetype = "dashed") +                      
  geom_errorbar(data=aux%>%filter(grepl("W",z)),aes(x = x, color = z,
                              ymax = intervalo_sup,               
                    ymin = intervalo_inf),
                width=0.3) + 

    geom_line(data=aux%>%filter(!grepl("W",z)),
              aes(x = x, y = media, color = z,group = z),
              size=0.5) +                      
    geom_errorbar(data=aux%>%filter(!grepl("W",z)),
                  aes(x = x, color = z,
                                ymax = intervalo_sup,               
                                ymin = intervalo_inf),
                  width=0.3)+
  labs(x = "x", y = "y", color = "Condition") +

  scale_color_manual(values=colores) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,7, by=1)) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.text=element_text(size=12)) +
  guides(color=guide_legend(ncol=2)) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14))+
  facet_wrap(~cb)
```

Comment: Hola @Patricio Moracho, estoy atascado con este problema. ¿Alguna idea/sugerencia? Un saludo!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El siguiente código genera una mejor aproximación a lo que esperas (esta vez usando tuberías)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
rm(list = ls())

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(stringr)

tribble(    ~y,    ~cb,   ~z,    ~x,
            1     , 0,   "H C R"    ,1,
            2     , 1,   "H C R"    ,1,
            2     , 0,   "I C R"    ,1,
            3     , 1,   "I C R"    ,1,
            1.5   , 0,   "H C W"    ,1,
            2     , 1,   "H C W"    ,1,
            2     , 0,   "I C W"    ,1,
            2     , 1,   "I C W"    ,1,
            3     , 0,   "H C R"    ,2,
            3     , 1,   "H C R"    ,2,
            0.5   , 0,   "I C R"    ,2,
            2     , 1,   "I C R"    ,2,
            2     , 0,   "H C W"    ,2,
            2     , 1,   "H C W"    ,2,
            1     , 0,   "I C W"    ,2,
            1     , 1,   "I C W"    ,2)-> datos

#Definimos los colores que usaremos
display.brewer.pal(11,name = "Spectral") 
# Que la línea de condición "H C" apareciera en el color anaranjado que utiliza la paleta "Spectral".
# Que la línea de condición "I C" apareciera en el color verde oscuro que utiliza la paleta "Spectral".
colores<-brewer.pal(n = 11, name = "Spectral")[c(3,9)]

#Preparamos los datos
datos %>%
  group_by(x, z, cb) %>%
  summarise(media = mean(y), 
            #Tube que simular la desvio sd() arrojaba NaN
            desvio = rnorm(1),                         
            error_est = desvio / sqrt(n()),             
            intervalo_sup = media + (2*error_est),       
            intervalo_inf = media - (2*error_est))%>%
  #Necesitamos tener en columnas las variables para color y tipo de linea
  mutate(Modelo=str_split(z," ")[[1]][3],
         Condicion=str_remove(z,Modelo)
            )%>%
  #Hacemos el grafico
ggplot(aes(x = x, y = media, color = Condicion,group = z)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=Modelo, color=Condicion),size=0.5)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = x, color = Condicion,
                    ymax = intervalo_sup,               
                    ymin = intervalo_inf),
                width=0.3)+
  scale_color_manual(values=colores) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,7, by=1)) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.text=element_text(size=12)) +
  guides(color=guide_legend(ncol=2)) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14))+
  facet_wrap(~cb)+
  # Modifica el titulo de las leyendas
  guides(color=guide_legend("Condición"),
         linetype=guide_legend("Modelo"))
```

Comment: @Gracias Rolando Tamayo. Tan solo un comentario, el cambio de número de columnas en `guides` debe ir al final del código para que el código responda a los cambios en número de columna.

Comment: @pyring te refieres a que las legendas aparezcan en dos columnas, una para modelo y otra para condición?

Comment: @Ronaldo Tamayo, más o menos. Era simplemente una nota informativa para quienes utilicen el código. Si se desean dos columnas se añade esto al final del código:   `guides(color=guide_legend("Condicion", ncol=1, order=1),
         linetype=guide_legend("Modelo", ncol=1))`

Comment: Es verdad gracias.